# Append option values to a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the push of a button, I'm iterating through a list of options in a select. I wish to append all of these option (values of the options) to a hidden fields, separated by a pipe `|`. So far I've come up with this, however, It just puts the last value of the option in the select in the hidden field?

```
//Select all cities
$jq("input#checkcities").click(function () {

    $jq(".select-cities > option").each(function () {
        var zipCodeValue = $jq(this).val();

        $jq(".select-cities option").attr("selected", "selected");
        $jq(".select-cities option").appendTo(".chosen-cities");

        //Put value of cities in hidden field.
        $jq('.hiddenFieldChosenCities').val(zipCodeValue);

    });
});
```

Comment: Why not append all the values to  a variable and then assign it to the hidden field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$jq('.hiddenFieldChosenCities').val($jq('.hiddenFieldChosenCities').val() + '|' + zipCodeValue);
```

Comment: Glad it helps for you.No "thnx" friend

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` method:

```
var zipCodeValues = $jq(".select-cities > option").map(function () {
                          return this.value;
                    }).get().join('|');

$jq('.hiddenFieldChosenCities').val(zipCodeValues);
```

Comment: Yes, `map` is what I'd use too. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/tDDXk/) for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value:

```
$jq('.hiddenFieldChosenCities').val($jq('.hiddenFieldChosenCities').val() + '|' + zipCodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create the string `zipvalues`
- Loop over the cities and append cities to `zipvalues`
- Finally set the hidden field value to `zipvalues`.

  ```
  // Select all cities
  $jq("input#checkcities").click(function () {
      var zipvalues = "";

      $jq(".select-cities > option").each(function () {
          var zipCodeValue = $jq(this).val();

          $jq(".select-cities option").attr("selected", "selected");
          $jq(".select-cities option").appendTo(".chosen-cities");

          zipvalues += "|" + zipCodeValue;
      });

      //Put value of cities in hidden field.
      $jq('.hiddenFieldChosenCities').val(zipvalues);
  });
  ```